# Add event handlers to AngularJS transclusion content

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-transclude

What is the proper way to add event handlers to transclusion content?  I do not want the consumers of my directive to add their own click handlers to the document.  The directive should handle it.  But I'm not sure how I correctly add handlers to the content passed with ng-transclude.

<s>Fiddle around: https://jsfiddle.net/hoe71p0e/12/</s> (can't get Angular.js and JSFiddle to work; my link function isn't being called)

**foo.html**

```
<my-foo>
    <button type="button">Foo</button>
</my-foo>
```

**foo.js**

```
return {
    template: "<div class='my-foo' data-ng-transclude></div>"
    link: function($scope, $elem, $attrs, $ctrl, $transclude) {
        $scope.foo = function() {
            console.log("this is never called");
        };

        $transclude(function(clone) {
            for (var i in clone) {
                if (clone[i].localName === "button") {
                    angular.element(clone[i]).attr("data-ng-click", "foo()");
                }
            }
        });
    }
};
```

**expected result** (clicking button should call foo)

```
<div class="my-foo">
    <button type="button" data-ng-click="foo()">Foo</button>
</div>
```

**actual result** (clicking button does nothing)

```
<div class="my-foo">
    <button type="button">Foo</button>
</div>
```

Notice, the `data-ng-click` attribute on the button is missing.

Also, I've seen several examples with something like this...

**broken.js**

```
$transclude(function(clone) {
    angular.element(clone).find("button");
});
```

...but those fail because `.find()` is not coming back with results, even though the inspector seems to think clone contains a "button".

Comment: it's not really obvious what you are trying to accomplish here.  What is the actual goal you are trying to achieve?  I'm not sure that I've ever encountered a reason for a directive to augment other content in this manner.

Comment: I'm thinking OP just wants to call his `ng-click` event in a transcluded directive and is explaining what they have tried so far

Comment: I've added a note explaining I do not want the consumers of my directive to be required to write a click handler to make the directive work.  Basically, my directive should have a required 'button' child, but the directive needs to handle the click behavior of the button; the consumer should not be responsible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't imagine you are even linking in this directive. In you fiddle, you are missing a few basic requirements e.g. `ng-app=""`, `restrict: 'E'` (required for 1.2.x) in an element style directive, and `transclude: true`. With remediation of those, we get a working example. Furthermore, I'm not sure what you are trying to do with `$transclude(function(clone) { /*...*/`, but I suspect this is unnecessary. 
Observe the following...

```
<my-foo>
    <button type="button" ng-click="foo()">Foo</button>
</my-foo>
```

---

```
.directive('myFoo', function() {
    return {
        transclude: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div class="my-foo" ng-transclude></div>',
        link: function($scope, elem, attrs) {
            $scope.foo = function() {
                console.log('this is called!');
            };
        }
    };
});
```

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/p16nec18/) - working demo

---

Per conversation the most straight forward approach you can take to solve this would be leveraging the [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) service and modifying the attribute on your `<button>` (once selected) element within your directive `link`. Inject `$compile` and observe the following...

```
.directive('myFoo', function($compile) {
    return {
        transclude: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div class="my-foo" ng-transclude></div>',
        link: function($scope, elem, attrs) {

            $scope.foo = function() {
                console.log('called')
            }

            var button = elem.find('button');
            button.attr('ng-click', 'foo()');
            $compile(button)($scope);
        }
    };
});
```

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/wbaxdz1o/) - `$compile` demo

Comment: I assure you, in the actual code I'm working from, the link function is being called.  The whole point is that the consumer of my directive should not have to add their own click handler.  That's why I'm using $transclude (incorrectly, apparently...)

Comment: okay I think I see what you are trying to do. Should be a few ways to do it. Check out [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xuyjv804/) and let me know if this is the direction you're leaning towards? @richremer

Comment: and [another way](https://jsfiddle.net/xuyjv804/1/) we could do it via `$compile`

Comment: or even a possibly [better way](https://jsfiddle.net/wbaxdz1o/). Still using `$compile`, but just adding the attribute to the element instead of swapping the markup. I'd say this is the best alternative approach @richremer

Comment: Yes!  That's exactly what I was looking for.  If you want to update the answer with any of those fiddles, I'll accept.

Comment: sweet! Glad we got it working together. Updated answer happy coding :) @richremer